# How to Place Whats app share button below Blogger Post

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, blogger

Assist me how to add Whats App share button below post to share the post.

I Have CSS on my website like below -

```
.tl-postShare{text-align:right;}
.tl-postShare ul{display:inline-block;}
.tl-postShare ul li{margin:0;}
.tl-tagnShare{position:relative;overflow:hidden;line-height:45px;margin-top:25px;}
.tl-postShare .tl-social-icons.icon-circle .fa{margin-right:7px}
.tl-postShare h6{display:inline-block;font-size:15px;margin:0 10px 0 0;line-height:35px;}
```

And HTML like this -

```
 <div class='tl-postShare pull-right'>
  <h6>Share To:</h6>
  <ul class='tl-colored-social icon-flat list-unstyled list-inline'> 
    <!-- Facebook -->
    <li class='tl-fbk'>
     <a expr:href='&quot;http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=&quot; + data:blog.url' rel='nofollow' target='_blank' title='Share on Facebook'>
       <i class='fa fa-facebook'/>
     </a>
    </li>
    <!-- Twitter -->
    <li class='tl-twt'>
     <a expr:href='&quot;http://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=&quot; + data:post.title + &quot;&amp;url=&quot; + data:post.url' rel='nofollow' target='_blank' title='Share on Twitter'>
       <i class='fa fa-twitter'/>
     </a>
    </li>

    <!-- WhatsApp -->

    <!-- Pinterest -->
    <li class='tl-pnt'>
     <a expr:href='&quot;http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=&quot; + data:post.url + &quot;&amp;media=&quot; + data:post.thumbnailUrl + &quot;&amp;description=&quot; + data:post.title' rel='nofollow' target='_blank' title='share on Pinterest'>
       <i class='fa fa-pinterest'/>
     </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I just need to add a share button for WhatsApp along with these buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the latest API from whatsapp https://wa.me/ ,

Share pre-filled text with contact selection

> https://wa.me/?text=urlencodedtext

Open Chat Dialog for a particular WhatsApp user

> https://wa.me/whatsappphonenumber

Share pre-filled text with a particular user (Combine above two):

> https://wa.me/whatsappphonenumber/?text=urlencodedtext

Comment: you have to formulate it according to your requirement.

Comment: Here is my Code. But it is unvisible after twitter icon. But when i click on it working fine.... [<!-- Whats app -->
<li class='tl-wts'>
 <a expr:href='&quot;https://wa.me/?text=&quot; + data:post.title + &quot;&amp;url=&quot; + data:post.url' rel='nofollow' target='_blank' title='Share on whats app'>
<i class='fa fa-whatsapp' />
  </a>
 </li>]

Comment: Dear @shyam-tayal, Could you please write the proper code for me. like above showing for Facebook.

Comment: Your code seems good, the problem might be with font awesome icon loading , try it replainc with a string text and click to check functionality , if everything seems to work , replace back fa fa-whatsapp and inspect fontawesome css for issue.

Comment: Dear, I am not very much expert in coding. Please can you tell me how to fix it as I am confused.

Comment: Done with this code Thanks for your time and suggestion............. [.tl-colored-social .fa-whatsapp,.tl-social-icons .fa-whatsapp:hover{background-color:#25d366}]

Answer (score 0):

Check out the results of going to https://wa.me/?text=urlencodedtext.  I see...

> ERROR
>
> PAGE NOT FOUND

I recommend you try one of the following formats:

```
https://api.whatsapp.com/send?text=YourShareTextHere
https://api.whatsapp.com/send?text=YourShareTextHere&phone=123
```

Here you get to indicate whether to have a phone number or not, because typically, you want someone to share the app with someone *they* know, not with someone that *you* know, which would be pointless.  Remember to use the `api.whatsapp.com` domain, and not the `wa.me` domain, and you'll be cooking!

If you are interested in watching a project that keeps track of these URLs, then check us out!: https://github.com/bradvin/social-share-urls#whatsapp

[image: Social Share URLs]